# Shared assets between angular libraries

Tags: angular, sass, angular-library, angular16

I have 2 libraries on my project, let's call them ui1 and layout2.
The first one exports assets that contains a file called cores.scss.

On the second library I want to import that file like **@import ui/assets/cores.scss** on a button.component.scss but I didn't find any way to do so.
The only way that works, for now, its the full path **@import "../../../../ui/src/assets/scss/cores.scss"**.

So, I don't want to do that, and if there is any way to simplify this I'd like to know.

Thanks!

**Edit**

I forgot to say that the angular version is the 16.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths